# Flatline in write IOPS in RDS. What does it means?

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, rds

Yesterday, I have seen below chart in Write IOPS. It was showing flatlined around 11:57 EDT (GMT - 4) and it lasted until around 14:04 EDT (GMT -4).

[image: IOPS]

When I checked after a day, I didn't find same for that period. I see normal write IOPS for that period.

What could be the reason of flatlined for those 2 Hrs?

Comment: can you look at the raw data around in rds that time to verify what was going on? Maybe there was some issues with collecting the data?

Comment: What do you mean by raw data?

Answer (score 3):

That graph is showing that in that period no data was received by CloudWatch. That the information was later filled in means the data found its way to the monitoring system.

It's probably just a glitch. It could've been something as simple as a disk failure or lost block on CloudWatch that was restored later, data that took a while to read from a queue, etc.

I wouldn't worry about it.